# how to break width: min-content responsively?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Please have a look at the codepen below…

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/bbblgmsp/pen/ExyEppm?editors=1100)

```
.post {
    display: inline-block;
    width: min-content;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 4px;
    margin-left: 4px;
}

.post > div {
    display: inline-flex;
}

img {
    height: 200px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.postContainer {
    display: flex;
    padding: 5px;
}

span {
    display: block;
}
```

It does what I want, the images are inline and the text within the same parent as the images breaks at the total width of the images.

But I struggle with the responsive behaviour. Obviously I want the line of images to break when the width reaches the viewport width and the divs to never be wider than the body.

Any ideas? Thanks for help!

Comment: flex-wrap: wrap;

Comment: it's not breaking the display: inline-flex that is the problem but rather breaking width: min-content. Any ideas?